# how to store and retrieve user-specific data

Tags: java, serialization, profile

I am working on a first project, a FlashCard app.

I would like to create a `profile` for every single user so that the user can make individual settings.

Besides that, I would like to organize the users's data around that profile. For example, I want to create a folder for every profile in which the users' `serialized files are being stored`

1. What is an appropriate format to store this type of data?

Intuitively, I would opt for `xml`. I have not worked with it yet, though.

2. What is the general `workflow` when working with profiles and serialized data

Here, I would `check at program start whether any profiles exist at all`.

If that's the case the user should be able to either add or load a profile. Otherwise the user should be prompted to create a profile.

Once, a profile has been loaded, I would `deserialize` all the data that is `associated` with this particular `profile`.

Does that make sense?

Cheers, 
Adnrew

Comment: What are you serializing?  In Java lingo, serialaizing an Object is what you do when you want to write it to disk or a stream.  But sometimes you really want to write data from an Object into a database or file.

Comment: I am serializing objects created by users (flashCards, Decks) and write them into files.

Comment: OK...when you use the Java serialization API it handles most of your concerns.  I believe the serialized object will be stored as a binary file.

Comment: Sure it does. My question is more about the profile rather serialization part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unless you want to share the profile data with other programs, you can simply use Java default serialization mechanism. Add other fields to the data structure as necessary

`public class Profile implements java.io.Serializable {
      private String name;
      public String getName() {
          return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }
 }`

The file will be stored in binary format. So you can give it any extension you want, e.g. profile1.dat

2. By using `ObjectInputStream` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html and `ObjectOutputStream` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html you can easily serialize / deserialize your profile data or any other data you need to write into files

First you would define the directory structure where to store your profile data. It could be in the same directory with application, say "profiles/". When the program starts it checks if there are any profile data files in the "profiles/" directory, if yes it will list them for the user to choose, if not it will prompt the user to create a new one.

Comment: Thank you nice approach. Just one question say I have a profile "profile01". The user now creates data say a DeckObj that holds some CardObjects. How would I connect the two (the profile, and the data created by that profile i.e. it's user)? I have read that java automatically serializes the objects that are associated with an object. Thus, is it correct to just add a Container that holds the objects associated with the profile in this case Decks to the profile class. Do the other classes that are recursively being serialized also need to implement Serializable or only the "top-class" ?

Comment: Typically you want to write a single file to the disk. So profile01 would contain everything needed for a single user. Preferences, data, settings, etc., which means Profile class needs to have fields - references to these things so that you can easily write the instance of Profile to disk and read back from it. Hence, Profile class might have following fields:
`private Deck deck;
private Preferences preferences;
private Settings settings;`
Yes all custom classes must implement java.io.Serializable to be serialized, most of the standard library classes and all primitive data types implement it